# How to check if an element has a hover property and do something to another element in css

Tags: html, css

So I'm try to make something in C.S.S and i want to make a drop-down kind think and i don't know how to check if an element has a hover property and do something to another element in C.S.S how to do that?

example:

if(element 1 has hover) {
 do something to element 2
}

source:
http://pastebin.com/EaKimzpP

Comment: use `:hover` psuedo class..

Comment: i have tried doing this 
`.tag1:hover .tag2 { do things to the different tag }`

Comment: CSS and HTML does not have that capability, try using JQuery or javascript

Comment: yeah well i can use JavaScript but how??

Comment: how your html markup looks like ???? .....

Comment: github repo i meant

Comment: Na nobody wants to get a repo ... include your relevant code here, and make a fiddle or codepen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes in two parts:

1. To see if hover is enabled, look at the tag, and see if the  has a tag:hover element in the CSS.
2. To action something else on the page based on hover, then you need JQUERY:

   $().hover(
     function() {
        Do Something;
     }
   );

Hope this helps.

Adding a reference from W3Schools to aid you in Drop down menu development: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

update 1:
This example provides a solution that allows you to adjust for transitions.  Requires JQUERY library:

https://toddmotto.com/html5-and-jquery-super-simple-drop-down-nav/

Comment: i don't really like using external libraries or anything else but thanks if i don't have any other option the ill do this thanks anyways

Comment: if you are just making a hyperlinked dropdown, you don't need external libraries, just CSS.  however, i would suggest all CSS is on it's own page, linked back to your table.

Comment: i want to make the first element visible and then set the transition to .5s and then set the height bigger

Comment: transitions and other things are part of javascript/jquery, in which the easiest path is a jquery library.  if you are asking recommendations for this, you might want to ask another question.

Comment: Updated my answer with a JQUERY answer so you can alter transitions and other options

Comment: welp ill try jquery thanks

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of jquery much love and good job

Comment: no problem. anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery like this:

```
$('tag1').hover(function(){ 

         $('tag2').method();

});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: it helps but i know jquery already but thanks anyways